# STM32F4 How to stop triple interleaved mode?

Tags: adc, stm32, stm32f4, dma, stm32f4-discovery

I am using triple interleaved mode with DMA in STM32F429 and have problem stopping it.

It should be stopped by `HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStop_DMA(&hadc1)`, but while debugging it gives `HAL_DMA_ERROR_NO_XFER` error during `HAL_DMA_Abort` function. I suspect it thinks DMA is busy, however I issue `HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStop_DMA(&hadc1)` in `HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback`, which implies that conversion is completed (and I also use normal mode, not circular, so no transfers should occur).

I start the conversion by button press, the first conversion working, but because ADC is not stopped the second conversion (on second button press) never occurs. I checked the circular mode - it works fine, data is updated all the time.

I've found some mentions of this error on internet (like [this](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/issues/4261) and [that](https://community.st.com/thread/34213-stm32f7-hal-110-adc-migration-problem), but not much help.

Here is my code, hope everything is clear. I omitted some unrelated stuff like RCC config, CubeMX boilerplate, etc.
I already tried turning off ADC2 and ADC3 before stopping ADC1 (although they seem to be stopped after ADC1, based on [this](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/targets/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32F3/device/stm32f3xx_hal_adc.c) example. Its for STM32F3 but I suppose it is similar in F4 too).
I tried using DMA access mode 2, however from datasheet I'm sure it needs to be access mode 3 because I use 8 bit resolution.
I also tried to change `PeriphDataAlignment` and `MemDataAlignment` between BYTE, HALFWORD and WORD, but no result too.
Also tried to put `HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStop_DMA(&hadc1)` in main function after some delay (though maybe using it in callback is not good), but it doesn't change anything.

I have no idea what I am supposed to do, was changing code here and there for 5 hours with no result.

stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c

```
void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(hadc->Instance==ADC1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA3     ------> ADC1_IN3 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Peripheral DMA init*/

    hdma_adc1.Instance = DMA2_Stream0;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_0;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
    hdma_adc1.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(hadc,DMA_Handle,hdma_adc1);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 1 */
  }
  else if(hadc->Instance==ADC2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC2_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC2_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**ADC2 GPIO Configuration    
    PA3     ------> ADC2_IN3 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC2_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC2_MspInit 1 */
  }
  else if(hadc->Instance==ADC3)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC3_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC3_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC3_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**ADC3 GPIO Configuration    
    PA3     ------> ADC3_IN3 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC3_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC3_MspInit 1 */
  }

}
```

main.c

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "usb_device.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "usbd_cdc_if.h"
#define ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH 14
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc2;
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc3;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
uint8_t ADCBuffer[ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC2_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC3_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* AdcHandle)
{
    HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStop_DMA(&hadc1);
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc3);   // Although it doesn't matter
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc2);   // since prev function returns error
}
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
    MX_ADC3_Init();
    MX_ADC2_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    HAL_Delay(1500);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0) == 1)
        {
            HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc3);
            HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc2);
            HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*) &ADCBuffer, ADC_BUFFER_LENGTH);
            HAL_Delay(500);
        }
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/* ADC1 init function */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode;
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_8B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

        /**Configure the ADC multi-mode 
    */
  multimode.Mode = ADC_TRIPLEMODE_INTERL;
  multimode.DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAACCESSMODE_3;
  multimode.TwoSamplingDelay = ADC_TWOSAMPLINGDELAY_5CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeConfigChannel(&hadc1, &multimode) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/* ADC2 init function */
static void MX_ADC2_Init(void)
{

  ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode;
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc2.Instance = ADC2;
  hadc2.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc2.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_8B;
  hadc2.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc2.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc2.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc2.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.EOCSelection = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  } 

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc2, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/* ADC3 init function */
static void MX_ADC3_Init(void)
{

  ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode;
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc3.Instance = ADC3;
  hadc3.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc3.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_8B;
  hadc3.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc3.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc3.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc3.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc3.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc3.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc3.Init.EOCSelection = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc3, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/** 
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream0_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn);

}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler */ 
}
```

Comment: This is the problem with HAL. It is extremely difficult to make it working in any more complex configuration. Try the bare registers, and you will get the control back, without need of reading those ridiculous libraries

Comment: @PeterJ_01, I am thinking about it. The only thing that holds me back is that I doubt I can do any good "idiot-proof" code, like maybe I will try to change some registers during processing and it will corrupt the microcontroller. Although it is unlikely, but still kinda scary. I guess I need to learn in-depth about inner configuration and try to implement it. Well, I will write back if I have any solution to it.

Comment: `registers during processing and it will corrupt the microcontroller` do not believe in everything you have found on internet. I

Comment: Try to stop using disable interrupt of dma, then if you want to retreive next data just enable it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with HAL. It is extremely difficult to make it working in any more complex configuration. Try the bare registers, and you will get the control back, without need of reading those ridiculous libraries – PeterJ_01 Sep 8 '17 at 23:37

Answer (score 1):

HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStop_DMA sets state to HAL_ADC_STATE_ERROR_DMA because HAL_DMA_Abort function returns HAL_DMA_ERROR_NO_XFER. One possible solution is to clear this bit by calling CLEAR_BIT:

```
HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStop_DMA(&hadc1);
CLEAR_BIT(hadc1.State, HAL_ADC_STATE_ERROR_DMA);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback function was not running a second time. I looked into the HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStop_DMA as the issue since it was returning an error. I tried adding "CLEAR_BIT(hadc1.State, HAL_ADC_STATE_ERROR_DMA);" as another commenter recommended but that did not work for me.

What did work for me was changing the option "DMA Continuous Requests" to "Enabled" in the Device Configuration Tool.

My code is below:

```
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc2);
HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(&hadc1, samplesA32, nsamples);
while(adc_flag){
    // wait for the ADC to do its thing
    // adc_flag is cleared in the HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback function
}
HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc2); // stop ADC2
HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStop_DMA(&hadc1); // stop ADC1
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with a STM32F303. As mentioned by Casey what did help was:

- set 'DMA Continuous Requests' to ENABLED
- set 'DMA Request Settings' to 'Circular'

Seems that with this settings the DMA is still somehow active, preventing the `HAL_DMA_ERROR_NO_XFER`error